# Please burninate (and blacklist) the "rocket-science" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

For a site supposedly wholly and unabashedly devoted to rocket science, this tag is kinda superfluous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Agreed. Might I add that we already have such tags as [rockets](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rockets) / [rocket](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocket), many more specific ones, and also the [science](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) tag (the latter also quite possibly superfluous and questions that use them should be checked if they could be re-tagged with more specific / descriptive ones). So yes, *superfluous²*.

I however propose synonymizing [rocket-science](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocket-science) with [rockets](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rockets) (on grounds of going through the questions that use them and noticing they are all about rockets and none about rocket science that isn't about rockets LOL), with the latter being a merged master, so the system automatically replaces former with the latter (all existing ones and on submit), while keeping former as a select option during question tagging for easier searching. *"Burniation"* and *"blacklistion"* seem rather severe tho, despite the temptation!! :)

---

**Update** (Jan. 13, 2015): [Done](https://space.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms)! Here's how these two tags were merged and synonymized:

[image]